# Filtering objects according to required and preferred attributes

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

This my `opportunity` object which is a part of my angular `app.component.ts` file. In my template(HTML of this component) I want to loop out different `skills` `backgrounds` `nationalities`etc. array using `*ngFor*`. So I've filtered out these array of objects based on a property `option` which can have only 2 values either `preferred` or `required`. I've implemented such logic inside my TS file using `filterByProperty()` function as shown below. Please help make this function more simplified and generalized.

```
opportunity: any = {
 "id": 526,
  "title": "Testing",
  "nationalities": [
    {
      "option": "preferred",
      "id": 479,
      "name": "India",
    }
  ],
  "skills": [
    {
      "option": "required",
      "id": 1153,
      "name": "Adobe Lightroom",
    },
    {
      "option": "preferred",
      "id": 77,
      "name": "Python",
    },
    {
      "option": "preferred",
      "id": 78,
      "name": "Ajax",
    },
    {
      "option": "required",
      "id": 147,
      "name": "3D Max",
    },
    {
      "option": "preferred",
      "id": 175,
      "name": "Aircraft Engine Technology",
    }
  ],
  "backgrounds": [
    {
      "option": "preferred",
      "id": 232,
      "name": "Biology",
    },
    {
      "option": "required",
      "id": 249,
      "name": "International relations",
    }
  ],
  "languages": [
    {
      "option": "required",
      "id": 18,
      "name": "English",
    },
    {
      "option": "preferred",
      "id": 31,
      "name": "Italian",
    }
  ]
}
```

My `app.component.ts` file

```
    import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html'
    })

    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  opportunity: any = {}; // Object value is shown above
  backgrounds: any = {
    preferred: [],
    required: []
  };
  skills: any = {
    preferred: [],
    required: []
  };
  languages: any = {
    preferred: [],
    required: []
  };
  nationalities: any = {
    preferred: [],
    required: []
  };

  ngOnInit() {
      this.filterByProperty();
  }

  filterByProperty() {
    this.skills.preferred = this.opportunity.skills.filter((i) => i.option === 'preferred');
    this.skills.required = this.opportunity.skills.filter((i) => i.option === 'required');
    this.backgrounds.preferred = this.opportunity.backgrounds.filter((i) => i.option === 'preferred');
    this.backgrounds.required = this.opportunity.backgrounds.filter((i) => i.option === 'required');
    this.languages.preferred = this.opportunity.languages.filter((i) => i.option === 'preferred');
    this.languages.required = this.opportunity.languages.filter((i) => i.option === 'required');
    this.nationalities.preferred = this.opportunity.nationalities.filter((i) => i.option === 'preferred');
    this.nationalities.required = this.opportunity.nationalities.filter((i) => i.option === 'required');
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not going to post an answer, because I don't have experience with angular, but why not parse `opportunities` once by iterating over its keys?

Comment: You can definitely answer the question because I'm just asking logic.. which will be written in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important piece of advice I can offer is **get rid of `any`**. By using `any` you are making Typescript ignore potential errors in your program. `opportunity` could be described with the following interfaces:

```ts
interface Opportunity {
  id: number
  title: string
  nationalities: Criteria[]
  skills: Criteria[]
  backgrounds: Criteria[]
  languages: Criteria[]
}

interface Criteria {
  option: 'preferred' | 'required'
  id: number
  name: string
}
```

Furthermore, the `backgrounds`, `skills`, `languages`, and `nationalities` properties should be correctly typed. In this case, I'd just add another interface, `SeparatedCriteria` isn't really the best name, but you can probably come up with a better one as you are more familiar with what each piece of data represents.

```ts
interface SeparatedCriteria {
  preferred: Criteria[]
  required: Criteria[]
}
```

`filterByProperty` has a lot of redundancy. At the very least, I would recommend defining `isRequired` and `isPreferred` local functions to help cut down on some of the noise.

However, this is still rather noisy especially as the logic is the same for each property - the only thing that changes is the key. With this in mind, we can define an array of keys, `['skills', 'backgrounds', 'languages', 'nationalities']` and assign `this[key].preferred` and `this[key].required`.

The trick to making this work correctly is to use both [intersection types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and [index types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types). It is possible to do this without knowledge of these topics, but the solution will not be type safe as it would be possible to add keys which aren't present in both `Opportunity` and `AppComponent` without receiving a compiler error. Here's how I would implement this function. You could now get rid of `isRequired` and `isPreferred` as they are only used once, but I believe it makes the logic more clear to leave them as is.

```ts
filterByProperty() {
  const isPreferred = ({ option }: Criteria) => option == 'preferred';
  const isRequired = ({ option }: Criteria) => option == 'required';

  const propertyKeys: Array<keyof AppComponent & keyof Opportunity>
    = ['skills', 'backgrounds', 'languages', 'nationalities'];

  for (const key of propertyKeys) {
    this[key].preferred = this.opportunity[key].filter(isPreferred);
    this[key].required = this.opportunity[key].filter(isRequired);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. And I'll surely implement the recommended changes.

Comment: Can you explain what does that mean in simple english. `Array<keyof AppComponent & keyof Opportunity>`

Comment: `keyof AppComponent` gives an intersection type of all the keys of `AppComponent`, this is all the property and method names on the class instance. `keyof Opportunity` gives `"id" | "title" | "nationalities" | "skills" | "backgrounds" | "languages"`, using `&` to combine them ensures you can only have keys which are contained in *both*`Opportunity` and `AppComponent`, then we just define an array of those keys.

Comment: Got it man.. well explained 